# Code optimization Android

Tags: java, android

I am doing a converter application for android and I have the following code. My question is: is there any way to optimize the code I have tried to do something with a switch statement but it didnt work properly.

```
private void fromMinute(double valueToConvert) {
        if (toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.toGrad) {

            toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert*0.01851851851852));

        } else if (toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.toDegree) {

            toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert*0.01666666666667));

        } else if (toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.toMinute) {

            toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert));

        } else if (toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.toSecond) {

            toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * 60));

        } else if (toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.toRadian) {

            toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * 0.0002908882086657));

        } else if (toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.toSextant) {

            toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * 0.0002777777777778));

        } else if (toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.toQuadrant) {

            toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * 0.0001851851851852));

        } else if (toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.toRevolution) {

            toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * 0.0000462962962963));
        }
    }
```

Comment: A `switch(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) { ... }` should work well (if the id is an integral type). An alternative would be to use a _map_.

Comment: switch internally uses if..else then what is the difference

Comment: Not always.  Switch at an assembly level can be (and is for longer ones) implemented as a lookup table of function pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  All of these just multiply by a constant.  So you can set up a map of id->conversion factor at the start:

```
Map<Integer, Double> conversions = new HashMap<>();
conversions.put(R.id.toSecond, 60);
...
```

Then the entire block above becomes

```
toOutput.setText(String.valueOf(valueToConvert * conversions.get(toRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId)));
```

Conversions should be created once in  the constructor of your class (or in onCreate) and use the saved version after that.